# Assigning Values to Combo Boxes

Tags: ms-access

I've created a combo  box in a form which lists all the flavours of ice-cream. However, I want to assign a number to each one (like in option boxes) e.g. chocolate = 1, strawberry =2 ect and would like that number to populate in the table the form is based on.

How would i go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with two columns.  Use that table as the rowsource for your combo box.  Make the second column your bound value for the combobox.